# Question about Functional analysis and coresponding f

Tags: functional-analysis

Hi guys I have been looking at the theorem.

Let x be in an normed vector space X. Then there is a bounded linear functional f on X such that $f(x)=||x||||f||$
such that the norm of f is 1.

I was thinking about the converse. For every f there exists and x with $||x||=1.$  such that f(x)=||x||
First is this true?
I think it is not because f on C[0,1] assigns each x from the space C[0,1] the value x(0) of x at 0. It has the norm 1 on the C so we can use the Hahn Banach to extend it to linear functional to $L^{\infty}[0,1]$, but now there is no element y in L^1 such that $F(x)= \int_0 ^1 xy dt$ for all x in C[0,1]

Comment: Try simple cases first. Take $f(x) = {1 \over 2} x$. Then $|f(x)| = {1 \over 2}$ for all $|x|=1$.

Comment: If I am following correctly this shows that $f(x)=||x|| $ is $f(x)=1$ which is contradiction to us defining f to be $f(x)=1/2x$ The problem I am having is hod do we know no such x exists. PS Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if $\|f\| <1$ then there can be no unit length $x$ such that $|f(x)| = 1$.

Even if $\|f\| = 1$, it is possible that $|f(x)| < \|f\|$ for all $\|x\| = 1$.

An example on $C[0,1]$ is $\phi(f) = \int_0^{1 \over 2} f(t) dt - \int_{1 \over 2}^1 f(t) dt$, we have $\|\phi\| = 1$, but we have
$|\phi(f)| < 1$ for all $\|f\| = 1$.